This code can be a HOOK system function in 5.15.0-73, but it is invalid at 5.15.0-113
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this
In the 5.15.0-113, 5.15.0-119 kernel, try the information of the Hook system calling table and replace it with a custom function. But after modification, it does not take effect normally.can I still use other ways to implement it?
unsigned long * sys_call_table;
unsigned int clear_and_return_cr0(void);
void setback_cr0(unsigned int val);
static int sys_mycall(void);

int orig_cr0;   
unsigned long *sys_call_table = 0;
static int (*anything_saved)(void); 
unsigned int clear_and_return_cr0(void) 
{
    unsigned int cr0 = 0;
    unsigned int ret;
    asm volatile ("movq %%cr0, %%rax" : "=a"(cr0)); 
        ret = cr0;
    cr0 &= 0xfffeffff;  
    //asm volatile ("movl %%eax, %%cr0" :: "a"(cr0));
    asm volatile ("movq %%rax, %%cr0" :: "a"(cr0)); 
    return ret;
}

void setback_cr0(unsigned int val)
{   

    //asm volatile ("movl %%eax, %%cr0" :: "a"(val));
    asm volatile ("movq %%rax, %%cr0" :: "a"(val));
}

static int sys_mycall(void)
{
    int ret = 12345;
    printk("My syscall is successful!\n");
    return ret;
}

static int __init init_addsyscall(void)
{
    printk("My syscall is starting。。。\n");
    sys_call_table = (unsigned long *)kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");
    printk("sys_call_table: 0x%p\n", sys_call_table);
    anything_saved = (int(*)(void))(sys_call_table[__NR_syscall]);  
    orig_cr0 = clear_and_return_cr0();  
    sys_call_table[__NR_syscall] = (unsigned long)&sys_mycall;  
    setback_cr0(orig_cr0);  
    return 0;
}

static void __exit exit_addsyscall(void)
{
    orig_cr0 = clear_and_return_cr0();  
        sys_call_table[__NR_syscall] = (unsigned long)anything_saved;   
        setback_cr0(orig_cr0);  
    printk("My syscall exit....\n");    
}

In versions 6.8.x and 5.15.100 or above, if you want to replace the system call function, in addition to replacing the system call table, what other ways can you do it?
Because in the latest version, it seems that using the replacement system call table does not take effect.

Thank you all, I've found a solution. By using ftrace to hook into the sys_call_table, we can perform a security check before the actual system function is called. This method is applicable to all current versions and is not affected by the latest kernel's removal of the system call table usage.
